# Multiple Operating Systems or ISO's Bootloader for a USB Stick?

Tags: boot, usb, iso-image, bootloader

I have no idea how to do this.

I have 7 iso's that I want to be able to easily boot from using a USB Stick and they are:

- Windows 7 Ultimate x86
- Windows 7 Ultimate x64
- Windows 8.1 x64
- Hirens BootCD
- Ultimate BootCD
- Windows XP Professional
- Ubuntu

Basically, I want to be able to boot my USB stick and instead of it just loading a single OS (like it does at the moment) I want a list of options ^ like above that I can choose and it will load that OS/ISO.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Have you looked into syslinux ? I believe that can boot ISOs

Comment: Have you checked on [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)? It allows to create bootable programs / ISOs, and you may be able to make it to boot Windows ISO perfectly fine just by editing the grub.

Comment: That looks like a really useful tool that I have not come across before +1.

Comment: Looks like YUMI is just syslinux bundled up nicely. Just an interesting note.

Answer (score 4):

Try Easy2Boot (Windows & Linux) - it allows you to plonk the .iso files on the USB key and they will be picked up in a menu dynamically generated at boot time.

As a bonus, to test your USB key, it includes QEMU so you give it a whirl without having to reboot!

http://www.easy2boot.com/download/

I had an issue with their download server, but they have a Google driver mirror listed too.

This requires another tool as a prerequisite:
http://www.rmprepusb.com/documents/release-2-0

I found your question when I wanted to do pretty much the same thing myself... I hope this helps!

Comment: this util is just amazing! I have been able to create that usb on just minutes, and adding ISOs to it is so simple! Great tip, thank you.

Comment: The links are dead.. Now searching for the possible new location.

Comment: Are you two advertising? The answer seemed to imply this is only a matter of dropping iso files into USBs. It is way more complicated than that.

Comment: Which two? It isn't necessarily easy with the method described above, but it was the only way I knew at the time which was *possible*.

Answer (score 2):

#### Making from Windows

I have had great success using [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), it's nice and easy and it supports custom ISOs (keep it updated for newest distros though).

You can also try [SARDU](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/sardu-multiboot-usb-creator-windows/) and [XBOOT](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/xboot-multiboot-iso-usb-creator/).

[Easy2Boot](http://www.easy2boot.com/make-an-easy2boot-usb-drive/) works on both Windows and Linux. I haven't tried it though.

#### Making from Linux

I've tried many, unfortunately most are not as stable and nice as YUMI.

[MultiSystem](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/) works alright (although sometimes it's buggy), with MultiSystem having a lot more functionality and customization (including persistent data partition sizes). It is also made by French people, so you may see some tooltips being French, but you can get by with icons and the mostly localized English interface.

I've also used [multibootusb](http://www.multibootusb.org/download) simple, works well but you have to type in the *.iso filename to boot into it (perhaps due to an error/by design?).

I've used [UNetbootin](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/using-unetbootin-to-create-a-linux-usb-from-linux/) (available from Ubuntu Universe repo).

Most of these programs are front-ends to Syslinux.
You can also do this manually on Linux: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/

Answer (score 1):

Buy an isostick [isostick from amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008S4XY08)

I bought one and you put a micro sd or SHXC card in it up to 64gb and it give you a boot menu on every other boot up.  Is it perfect no, but it works well enough.  The author is working on a patch to fix UEFI bios machines.

Visit [isostick](http://www.isostick.com)

for more details

**it is better than what your trying to do**  I have tried multi-boot loaded a most don't work with one or another ISO.  Some like linux, but will hate your windows and vice versa.

I will never go back to doing it the old software way.

Comment: They're pretty expensive :s

Comment: Agreed they are kind of expensive, but the ease of use makes up for that.  You just drag and drop your ISO on to the software and wait for completion and its done.  You need the software for ISO >4gb,but for eveything else just copy and paste the ISO on and that is all that is required.

Comment: I just managed to put Hirens, Ultimate, FalconFour, Windows XP Pro, Windows 7, Windows 8.1, Ubuntu all onto a USB and all of them boot. The only one what doesn't work is "Kon-Boot" but that looks like it's a problem with Kon-Boot's "Dummy Bios detection", all done via WinSetupFromUSB

Comment: 99 $ is a lot. I wonder what special hardware do they have in there that makes it so expensive

Answer (score 1):

I have used only one there may be others: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ or you could do it by hand but is more tedious work.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools available to do that, check it and pick right one for you

1. [MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.sourceforge.net/)
2. [XBOOT](https://sites.google.com/site/shamurxboot/download)
3. YUMI – Multiboot USB Creator
4. RMPrepUSB

Answer (score 1):

First copy all ISO files to another USB stick or external drive. Sequentially write each windows ISO to the flash drive using rufus and install it on a separate partition. Finally, use universal USB installer to create a bootable Ubuntu iso and install. After the install, each operating systems will be available in the grub bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever consider a PXE server instead? i.e. you can get your boot menu up and running in very short time with [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html).
(I'm related to Serva development).