# Is there a way to create 1 usb stick which can install multiple versions of windows and linux?

Tags: boot, usb, multi-boot, liveusb

Well the question is clear. The reason behind it is, that I think it would be handyt to have 1 64 GB USB stick on my keychain to repair or reinstall computers with. I was thinking of some kind of on stick bootloader or something.

Comment: Oops after adjusting my search query I found [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/703883/multiple-operating-systems-or-isos-bootloader-for-a-usb-stick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tool can be useful if you only want to boot a Live Image.

[Nice Tool Description - Click here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

BTW: Very nice idea!

Comment: Thanks, but I do know how to create a USB stick with just 1 operating system. I'd like to know how to do it with multiple

Comment: "It can be used to create a Multiboot USB Flash Drive containing multiple operating systems"

Comment: You are right!!

Comment: @Thomas Hey, have you tried it with YUMI? How was you experience ? I wanna try it too!

Comment: made the stick, but to be honest I didn't have the time to try it out yet